# calling ASP function from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

hello i have this question i was trying to find a way to call a javascript function from asp controllers and i did here is the code  :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function hello() { 
        alert("hello world")
    }
</script>
<  /head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="buttonme" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:hello()" 
 Text="click" />
```

now lets say i have this code behind function

```
    Public Sub msg()
      MsgBox("hello world")
    End Sub
```

and i want to call it from a javascript function so it will be like controller----call---> javascript ---call--->code behind

is there is a way to do this

Comment: since this is a web app, when the MsgBox is fired, it will only popup a box on your server, it will not popup a box on the client. You will need to use ajax in order to use code-behind files for functions.

Comment: @Juventus18 thanks for your reply this is just an example it can do any thing

Comment: Take a look at his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10893954/1268570 this is an alternative using Rest services (without .svc files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your method in a class somewhere in your web application.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Msg()
{
     return "Hello world";
}
```

Add a script manager with EnablePageMethods=true in your aspx page

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="someId" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Call the method in javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    PageMethods.Msg(onSuccess);
    function onSuccess(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use AJAX in some form and expose the ASP.NET method you want to call via HTTP.

Comment: is there is any other way to do this with out ajax

Comment: Not really, no.  If you want the browser-side code to call server-side code the communication mechanism is via AJAX (the XMLHttpRequest object).  What's wrong with using AJAX?  jQuery makes it quite easy to do.

Comment: i know it isn't hard , what i have is a linkbutton that calls a javascript function to open a new tab in my project but before opening this tab i need to update a session , so my problem know is to update this session before opening the new tab

Comment: Update the ASP.NET Session?  Any HTTP request back to the server from the browser will do that.  Is the content in your pop-up served from your application?

Comment: considering this OnClientClick="var url = 'CIP_frmCIPEventExplorePdf.aspx?ViewPDF=1&intCIPEventID=' + $('#intCIPEventID').val();parent.showNewTab(url, 'CIP Chart - PDF', 'CIP');"> i want this control to go to a code behind function update the session "" and then "" open the new page , this new page generat a pdf file with the old session if you reload the page you get the updated data

Comment: i will ask this in a different way i will send you the link ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040041/execute-vb-code-behind-before-java-script

Comment: @MinaGabriel why so insistent on not using ajax?