# How to call WCF operation from a HTML website?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm stuck on one small problem that stop development for a feature I'm trying to implement.

I currently have a WCF Web Service created with the following code:

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Sinvise.Service/")]
    public interface ISinvise
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Output(string value);
    }

    class SinviseService : ISinvise
    {
        second sec = new second();

        public void Output(string value)
        {
            sec.message(value);
        }
    }
```

Main Method:

```
var ip = getIP();
            Uri baseAddr = new Uri("http://"+ip+":60185/Sinvise");
            ServiceHost localHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SinviseService), baseAddr);
            Console.WriteLine("Current System IP: " + getIP());
            try
            {
                Process.Start(baseAddr.AbsoluteUri);
                localHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISinvise), new BasicHttpBinding(), "SinviseService");

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                localHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                localHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service initialized.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press the ENTER key to terminate service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                localHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oops! Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                localHost.Abort();
            }
```

The application sets up the web service to be called in my application, now what I want to do is use a HTML page to call the operations. They're simple operations that pass values across to the application.

Now I know that HTML can't do this on it's own, and PHP won't be an option on this end as it will require me to package a web server and PHP in my application deployment (which I can't do as my application requires payment therefore no opensource software can be included).

I am having a problem using jQuery as it can not be used in a cross domain manner.

The webservice is not related to ASP.NET but I need something that will allow users of my software to be able to use the HTML page to make calls to the web service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct and based on this:

> I am having a problem using jQuery as it can not be used in a cross domain manner.

Your service is in another domain, then do it the simplest way, create a REST service in **your domain** and then **wrap the call to the external service**

See this question

This is a walkthrough creating a REST service (without SVC file and this can be used in a ASP.Net or MVC app)

[Datalist Delete Command Event implementation using Page Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10893954/1268570)

This is a full application you can download that uses the REST service

http://sdrv.ms/LJJz1K

Example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "/DeleteFromService",
        Method = "DELETE")]
    void Delete(int id);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        // wrap here the call to your external service
        // simulate a long process
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

In the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function deleteFromService() {
            $.blockUI();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "DELETE",
                async: true,
                url: "/DeleteFromService",
                data: "3", // get your id to delete
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 
                    alert("done");
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        jQuery().ready(function () {
                        $("#myButton").click(deleteFromService);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but the thing is I have my HTML page like file://C:\index.html and my service is localhost:65201 obviously the HTML page can't communicate with it

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be something that doesn't require server-side code, you'll need to at least use client-side code. (JavaScript).

Here's an example of how to call a web service directly using JavaScript.:  http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2007/10/calling-asmx-web-services-directly-from.html

(More results than just this one come up with a [simple search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript%20calls%20to%20asp.net%20web%20service&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=javascript%20calls%20to%20asp.net%20web%20service&sc=0-40&sp=-1&sk=).)

Comment: As I pointed out it isn't an ASP.NET web service, the web service is generated from the code in my question

Answer (score 0):

As you said:-

`I am having a problem using jQuery as it can not be used in a cross domain manner`

But, this problem seem to got solved by using `ScriptManager` [**Not Tried though**]. See here for Full Sample step by Step

- http://pranayamr.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html under the heading `Solution 2 : Call WCF Service by Javascript`

But, refer both the solutions.

Comment: As i mentioned use REST services with JSON serializer . You can also user JSONP for your crossdomain issues. Take a look adn you will surely find it beneficial in your case . I hope so..

Comment: The comment is from the question and the solution is there in the link provided based on the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use HTML now. You should take a look at REST Services .Take a look at WCF Data Services or Asp.net WebApi. You can find lot of tutorials that will help you implement the services easily and let you quer using jquery in HTML.