# How do I do an AJAX post to a url within a class library but not the same IIS Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have been working with ajax and there has been no problems below is how my ajax post code look like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '<%=ResolveUrl("TodoService.asmx/CreateNewToDo")%>',
  data: jsonData,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  datatype: "json",
  success: function () {
    //if (msg.d) {
      $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_useridHiddenField').val("");
      $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_titleTextBox').val("");
      $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_destTextBox').val("");

      $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_duedateTextBox').val("");
      alert('Your todo has been saved');
     // }
  },

  error: function (msg) {
    alert('There was an error processing your request');
  }

});
```

However, the problem came up when I try to get the url to a webservice that is located in a class library within the same solution.

Comment: @Aristos I am saying how to pass the url like this url: '<%=ResolveUrl("TodoService.asmx/CreateNewToDo")%>' when the webservice is located in a class lirary not inside the website itself

Comment: Does the Class Library have a web accessible presence?

Comment: If it's a different application than yours that's considered an XSS (Cross-site scripting) and it is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

This [ASP.Net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1805440.aspx/1)

says If you want to put the webservice in the classlibrary, you could try placing the Webservice.asmx.cs file in the class library and place the Webservice.asmx file in the web application project, and then using jquery to consume it in the .aspx page

Answer (score -1):

If it's a different application than yours that's considered an XSS (Cross-site scripting) and it is not allowed.

You could however wrap the call to the external service in your own application ([let's say in a REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967315/1268570)) and just call your service from jquery

Comment: Not if it's on the same webserver. I don't think you understand what "cross site" means.